# How do I list these volunteer events on my resume?

Tags: resume, applications

I've done various volunteering activities before that were long term, but in the past couple months I've been volunteering each weekend at 5k races or local marathons. Each race is put on by a different group and benefits a different charity, so they don't really have anything in common except being races. How do I list these on my resume without putting each separate event?

Comment: Are these volunteer activities related to the job you're building your resume for?

Comment: @Thalantas I don't think the two are duplicates. The linked question is asking how to list volunteer work, in general. This question is specifically asking how to list frequent volunteering that is for many different organizations but are similar in nature.

Answer (score 3):

First you want to ensure you're adding things relevant for a job you're looking at applying for. Always keep your resume tailored towards the position you're seeking. If you're looking for a programming job you need to identify the things that will carry over from the volunteer activities. Organizing a 5k run doesn't have much carry over. So things like the organization skills would help you out if you're looking at a Project Manager or Lead position, but a junior programmer not really. The best way to identify the carry over is to compare the job posting's requirements and nice to haves and go from there.

As far as where to put them? I'd lump them together at the end of the resume personally. They're not likely to have a large impact on your hiring but may help set you apart from an equally qualified candidate.

Comment: Or mention your volunteering in the cover letter as part of the unofficial "here's who I am", perhaps. If you're a recent graduate, extracurriculars may be a helpful indicating of who you are and what you get excited about; after you've got some work experience they tend to become footnotes at best unless they showcase something this employer is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I list these on my resume without putting each separate event?

You could have a heading, followed by a general sentence indicating what you did.

Something like:

```
Volunteer Activities
Volunteer Timekeeper at various local races.
```

Answer (score 0):

Linkedin says that 1/5 of employer choose also on the volunteer experence.
So you should put in the resume for sure.

Actually i would write a separate section after "working experience" section and "education" section OR write that you partecipate in volunteer events in a summary(if you have one) at the start of your CV .